# ZFTool2 - Error Creating Project

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zftool2

I am new to the Zend Framework. I just started using ZFTool 2. The documentation says I can create a project by running the command

```
zf.php create project <path>
```

When I try to create a project

```
C:\wamp\www>zf.php create project quickstart
```

I encounter the following error

```
Error: I cannot find the autoloader of the application.
Check if C:\wamp\www contains a valid ZF2 application.
```

All other commands seem to work fine except the above. I wouldn't expect the command to be trying to find the autoloader of the application in my www folder anyway escpecially because am attempting to create a new project

EDIT:
The same thing also happens when i run the command

```
C:\wamp\www>zf.php version
```

Comment: thx... but i dont have C:\ZendFramework-XXX\library, i installed via composer. Do i point it to the vendor\zendframework\ instead

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26397962/using-zftool-in-a-more-efficient-manner

Answer (score 0):

When you use composer to install zftool then it will auto install into vendor\zendframework\zftool
So that, you only need cd to root of application and then point to folder ztool
(example: your application folder that store in c:\xampp\htdocs\zend)

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\zend> php ./vendor/zendframework/zftool/zf.php version
It will output bellow:
ZFTool - Zend Framework 2 command line Tool
The ZFTool is using Zend Framework 2.5.1
```

and it'll work for you.
http://rao5s.vn